# Design A for Revit fails with : DasZip failed with exit code = 1

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am successfully running jobs on Design Automation, but having issues with nested links. For models with one link I can successfully run jobs, but run into download failues when there is a nested link. Here is my workitem:

```
{
    "activityId": "WDQIfAV8PqNa9XSKPmv6MDu3xAtLGfXI.Revit2ProtoExporterActivity+OV",
    "arguments": {
        "rvtFile": {
            "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/cb86d20e-99de-4c70-baab-4e973b98841b.rvt",
            "localName": "Root.rvt",
            "headers": {
                "authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlU3c0dG..."
            },
            "zip": true,
            "pathInZip": "Root.rvt",
            "references": [
                {
                    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/994e304d-056b-437f-98b3-708f264060e1.rvt",
                    "headers": {
                        "authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI5m1Fzc..."
                    },
                    "zip": true,
                    "pathInZip": "NestedLink.rvt",
                    "references": [
                        {
                            "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/dc747faa-d613-41a7-9957-ea5c892163b0.rvt",
                            "headers": {
                                "authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6I..."
                            },
                            "localName": "NestedNestedLink.rvt"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "params": {
            "url": "data:application/json,{\"ViewName\": \"{3D}\"}"
        },
        "result": {
            "verb": "post",
            "url": "https://staging-appliedvrabs-pa.sandbox.googleapis.com/upload/v1/modelsync/receiveFile/mjJtrtc9XpCnWbxEKn5ks/aWQP85k2KBEJvCcdYQfuc/S08xVSkeiIB-pdessJemr/1",
            "headers": {
                "authorization": "Bearer ya29.c.b0AXv0zTOAE9AxL..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the response that I am getting:

```
[06/02/2022 22:44:31] Starting work item 16af701f60244a6581cc7fed7948ee3c
[06/02/2022 22:44:31] Start download phase.
[06/02/2022 22:44:31] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/cb86d20e-99de-4c70-baab-4e973b98841b.rvt'
[06/02/2022 22:44:31] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/994e304d-056b-437f-98b3-708f264060e1.rvt'
[06/02/2022 22:44:31] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/dc747faa-d613-41a7-9957-ea5c892163b0.rvt'
[06/02/2022 22:44:31] Embedded resource [{"ViewName": "{3D}"}] is saved as file: T:\Aces\Jobs\16af701f60244a6581cc7fed7948ee3c\params.json.
[06/02/2022 22:44:31] End downloading file. Source=https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/dc747faa-d613-41a7-9957-ea5c892163b0.rvt,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\16af701f60244a6581cc7fed7948ee3c\NestedNestedLink.rvt,BytesDownloaded=5206016,Duration=430ms
[06/02/2022 22:44:31] End downloading file. Source=https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/cb86d20e-99de-4c70-baab-4e973b98841b.rvt,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\16af701f60244a6581cc7fed7948ee3c\zip_16.zip,BytesDownloaded=10422030,Duration=489ms
[06/02/2022 22:44:32] T:\Aces\Jobs\16af701f60244a6581cc7fed7948ee3c\zip_16.zip has been unpacked to folder T:\Aces\Jobs\16af701f60244a6581cc7fed7948ee3c.
[06/02/2022 22:44:32] End downloading file. Source=https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/994e304d-056b-437f-98b3-708f264060e1.rvt,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\16af701f60244a6581cc7fed7948ee3c\zip_17.zip,BytesDownloaded=10417965,Duration=788ms
[06/02/2022 22:44:32] Error: Unable to download file https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/994e304d-056b-437f-98b3-708f264060e1.rvt: DasZip failed with exit code = 1.
[06/02/2022 22:44:32] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase Downloading of job.
[06/02/2022 22:44:32] Job finished with result FailedDownload
```

Not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: our logs shows the error that "System.IO.IOException: The file 'T:\Aces\Jobs\16af701f60244a6581cc7fed7948ee3c\NestedNestedLink.rvt' already exists." when trying to unzip one of the downloaded zip file. Please double check if the zips have the same file names.

Comment: That would make sense actually. NestedLink.rvt is actually a zip file that contains NestedNestedLink. In production, I would be very difficult to know exactly which files already exist, If there was a way to download every Revit file as a singular file (not a zip folder containing cloud version) I could do that, but that's not really an option given how BIM 360 APIs work, any suggestions?

Comment: I posted an answer. See if this works or we can connect over email  tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Rahul, responded to you answer. We can connect via email tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks, I will include Eason and Emma.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is all you need:

```json
{
    "activityId": "WDQIfAV8PqNa9XSKPmv6MDu3xAtLGfXI.Revit2ProtoExporterActivity+OV",
    "arguments": {
        "rvtFile": {
            "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/cb86d20e-99de-4c70-baab-4e973b98841b.rvt",
            "headers": {
                "authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlU3c0dG..."
            },
            "zip": true,
            "pathInZip": "Root.rvt"
        },
        "params": {
            "url": "data:application/json,{\"ViewName\": \"{3D}\"}"
        },
        "result": {
            "verb": "post",
            "url": "https://staging-appliedvrabs-pa.sandbox.googleapis.com/upload/v1/modelsync/receiveFile/mjJtrtc9XpCnWbxEKn5ks/aWQP85k2KBEJvCcdYQfuc/S08xVSkeiIB-pdessJemr/1",
            "headers": {
                "authorization": "Bearer ya29.c.b0AXv0zTOAE9AxL..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I dropped the field `arguments.rvtFile.localName`. I also dropped `arguments.rvtFile.references[]`. The zip package from BIM 360 should contain the links nested in your `Root.rvt`. They would also be repath-ed to the relative folder. Did you need to include the references explicitly for any specific reason?

Judging from Emma's comment, the error might have been due to the fact that one of the root packages already unzipped the `NestedNestedLink.rvt`, and another package is trying to do the same.

Comment: So this actually wouldn't work. Here is how all the files are linked togehter:

Root.rvt -> Link.rvt -> NestedLink.rvt -> NestedNestedLink.rvt

Root contains Root.rvt and Link.rvt, but not NestedLink and NestedNestedLink. Also, this is just a sample that I am trying to get through. In production, I wouldn't know how all the files are connected. I suppose I can download everything first and upload what I need az a zip file, but that doesn't sound like a good solution. Can the VMs be setup to override the existing files when downloading links?